# Is there a way to determine if a form's text will fit in?

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, winforms

Is there a way to determine if the form's text property will fit in the top bar using the form's current width (or if it will be truncated with "...")?

[image]

Comment: [No](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/05/08/10613194.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might take a look into [`TextRenderer.MeasureText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To calculate the width of a caption text use this snippet:

```
var width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(caption, SystemFonts.CaptionFont).Width;
```

You could use the size of your Form, subtract a fixed value for the icon (if visible) and the buttons on the top right (depends on the OS version and on the visible state of the [Minimize] [Maximize] buttons) and check if it is still positive. This might not give you a perfectly accurate result, but it is probably the simplest approximation.

So far, this method seems to calculate a pretty accurate approximation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates an approximation of the available caption width
/// Depends on OS and theme
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Width</returns>
private int CalcAvaliableCaptionWidth()
{
    return
    // Form width
    Width
    // Icon
    - (Icon == null ? 0 : Icon.Width)
    // Minimize button (26 on Win8)
    - (MinimizeBox ? SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Width : 0)
    // Maximize button (26 on Win8)
    - (MaximizeBox ? SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Width : 0)
    // Close button (45 on Win8)
    - SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Width;
}
```

You might try my little verification WinForm application

[image: verification WinForm application]

Source code:
https://gist.github.com/CodeZombieCH/b9def0b0d9c41a98593a

Thanks to @Plutonix for the hint to `SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize`.

Comment: I am sure  you know that this answer is incomplete. How do you find if the resulting textSize will fit in the form Caption area free from standard buttons and icon for the context menu?

Comment: use `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize` to get the size of standard title bar buttons.  The number of them present will depend on other form props (MinimizeBox, ControlBox etc).

Comment: CodeZombie and @Plutonix, thanks, this worked perfectly!